# Possible to host a simple web form that submits to a MySQL db on a network drive

Tags: mysql, database, ms-access, web, data-entry

I am looking at some alternatives to collating information into a database and then running some SQL queries off that to produce some reports.

Now currently I have a MS Access(2003) on a network drive and my guys in the field will access this db and enter data via a MS Access Form. After this I have to then run queries (currently weekly) and export them to an excel spreadsheet.

Now I have some new starters + upgrading my MS office software and I am looking to make the DB more accessible (whilst staying secure) without having any need for software (ie a website) if possible. Now I know how to program a PHP form that will entered the data into a MySQL DB.

Here is my dilemma...The data we have is very sensitive information and if people get hold of it, it can open a lot of people to fraud, so i dont want to go and get a web hosting company involved. SO I was mentioned "why dont you run a MySQL db from your network drive".

SO my questions are to what are my options in this matter

1. IS it possible to run a private website via a network drive (say via XAMPP or something similar) and if so how would I approach it?
2. If not what alternative to MS Access is there that I can easily develop data entry forms on?

Thank you in advance,

Johan

Comment: sensitive data and Access generally don't go together very well, especially when you start involving direct access via external networks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's possible to run a website on a private network, though the "via a network drive" part of your requirement isn't clear. A website requires a web server (like WAMP or XAMPP or similar); you access this website via a URL; the URL can be embedded in a shortcut which resides on your network drive, if that's what makes you happy. The web server software can run on the same physical hardware as your network drive, but it's probably better if it runs on a machine of its own.

If you know how to build a secure website, it's probably safer than leaving an access database on a network drive. If you don't know how to build a secure website, it may well still be safer than leaving an access database on the network drive, **as long as the website can never be reached from outside your corporate network**, and your corporate network has sufficient security measures built in. If there's any way for an attacker to get access to your web page, and your site contains security vulnerabilities, the likelihood is that your data will get stolen.

Comment: Neville, 

Thank you for the quick reply. How would I approach setting it up that the website isn't public yet accessible to my field operatives?

Comment: If they can access the shared drive with the access DB, they presumably have a VPN or similar; they can use this VPN to access a webserver hosted on your local network.